# Permission rights with google maps

Tags: google, legal

I created an image in QGIS using the Google Maps layer and I would now like to publish this as part of an academic journal article. However, the journal editor has asked if I have permission to use the Google Maps base layer. Does anyone know if I need to obtain permission from Google to use this image?

Answer (score 5):

Google has a permissions tool [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1342531&page=ts.cs). When you click through the options, it seems like your use of the map (academic, in print-media) would probably fall under fair-use so long as you do not obscure the copyright.

Is it possible to make the same image using OpenStreetMap?

Comment: OSM would be the ideal solution for this.